# Why imported mdb database doesn't show any polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I've imported an MDB database to ArcMap but it doesn't show any polygon.
Do I have to modify something else after importing data? I  can only see the imported database tables

[image]

Comment: Do you know for certain that this was a personal geodatabase?  ArcGIS can only find geometries where geometries exist.

Comment: Is this MDB an Esri Personal Geodatabase?  Essentially, you need to make sure that the tables in the mdb that contain spatial information are registered as such by ArcGIS.  This would include ensuring that they contain an "OID" or "FID" field with a unique ID for each record.
An easy way to tell how ArcGIS sees this database is by looking at it through ArcCatalog.  When ArcGIS identifies a table as containing spatial data, it assigns a point, line or polygon icon to that table.  Otherwise it will have a generic icon, indicating attribute data only.